# How to efficiently add a formula to cells in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to give certain cells in Excel certain name and descriptions. I recorded a Macro and it produced the following output. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to write the code? I have to do this for several hundred cells before I copy the cells down. To be clear I am not asking HOW to add formulas I am asking what is the most efficient way that will use the least amount of resources.

```
    Range("J2").Select
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "User Team"

    Range("J3").Select
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VALUE(LEFT(RC[-1],4))"
```

Comment: You can assign one and the same formula to hundreds of cells at once like so: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J3:J500").FormulaR1C1 = "=VALUE(LEFT(RC[-1],4))"`. Since the formula is *relative* using *R1C1*-style it should work just fine for all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what sheet you are using you could probably use this:

```
Sheet1.Activate

Sheet1.Range("J2") = "User Team"

Sheet1.Range("J3") = "=DATE(LEFT(I3,4),MID(I3,6,2),MID(I3,9,2))"
```

Comment: No need to actually activate the sheet for that though. ;)